# Is there a solution to this unidirectional wave equation, with initial value $v=f(x)$ and $x=t^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, wave-equation, characteristics

unidirectional wace equation:

$$\frac{du}{dt}+c\frac{du}{dx}=0$$

The initial value $u=f(x)$ is given on the parabola $x=t^2$.

Is there a solution to this problem, discuss why the solution is unique and differentiable or discuss why there is no solution.

and is there a solution to the problem if $t\leq c/2$

Can someone help me how to start with this? Do I need Fredholm alternative to see how many solutions. Or what should be the first step. Characteristics maybe?

Comment: $u(x,t) = e^{i \omega (c t - x)}$ are solution for any $\omega$, and the initial condition is $u(x^2,x) = f(x^2)$, so decompose $f(x^2)$ on the $e^{i \omega (c x -x^2)}$ basis ?

Comment: $t$ is an independent variable, you cannot impose a condition such as $t\leq c/2.$

Comment: what you mean by decompose $f(x^2)$ on the $e^{i \omega (c x -x^2)}$ basis?

Comment: Your first stet is to plot the graph of the initial condition and characteristics in the same system of coordinates and..., well, conclude... Let me know if you are still interested in this question.

Comment: yes still interested! ill try to see what you mean now

Comment: With same system of coordinates, do you mean that $u=f(\tau)$, where $\tau$ is $x-ct$, and then for what does this mean for the initial condition?

Comment: Do i need to draw the straight characteristic lines? and in this same plot a function $\tau=t^2$, then for $t \leq c/2$ it doesnt cross a characteristic lines? @Artem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your initial condition on the curve defined by $x=t^2$. At the same time you should know that the characteristics to the transport equation are the strait lines
$$
x=ct+\xi,
$$
where $\xi$ is some constant, and your solution is constant along the characteristics.

Clearly, no matter what the value of $c$ the straight line with $\xi=0$ will cross the curve of the initial conditions twice, since we know that $f$ is arbitrary hence this will imply that in general on the same characteristic there will be two different initial conditions, hence no solution exists in general.

The case $t\leq c/2$ I will leave to you. You need to analyze your initial conditions and characteristics and conclude that...

Comment: You mean one of the intersections is at $x=0$? So this is only for $\xi=0$, or also for $\xi>0$, because the $f$ moves to the left right? and for $t\leq c/2$, it is not the case clearly because the time always stops before the second intersect would occur if im correct.

Comment: I am lost at your questions. How $f$ moves? How the time stops? Please read carefully what I have written, I think it is more than enough to finish this problem.

Comment: I thought that the $x=t^2$ was the $f$ that the transport equation moves to the left. I think I know what you wrote, and I can see that in the $x,t$ plot the straight line, with arbitrary $c$, will always intersect twice with $t^2$, but if you look for $t \leq c/2$ it will not have an intersect yet for the second time.But I dont understand why crossing the characteristic two times is a problem here, why isn't the solution just $u(x,t)=f(x-ct)$ here? would it not have been a problem if $f(x)=x^2$ instead of $f(x)=t^2$

Comment: The key your question is "But I dont understand why crossing the characteristic two times..."  The initial condition cannot intersect (in general) the characteristic in more than one point simple because along the characteristic your equation becomes an ODE, which needs only *one*   initial condition. Crossing characteristic twice means having two conditions for a first order ODE, which is in most cases has no solutions.